# How can I catch smart contract exception from web3

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am using `web3-react` to build Web UI which interacts with smart contract running in Ethereum Ganache network.

The contract has a method to create a sector in solidty:

```
function createSector(uint256 x, uint256 y, uint256 width, uint256 height) public payable {
    uint256 price = _calculateSectorPrice(width, height);
    Sector memory sector = Sector(x, y, width, height, price);
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) + msg.value >= price, "Insufficient funds");
    ...
  }
```

when the web calls this method, the `require` throws an error: `Insufficient funds`. But the UI doesn't get this specific error, instead it gets `ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract`. This error is too generic because it doesn't tell what the real error is.

The web3 code I have is:

```
await contract.methods
            .createSector(
              web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalI),
              web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalJ),
              web3.utils.toBigInt(1),
              web3.utils.toBigInt(1),
              { value: web3.utils.fromWei(cellPriceInWei, 'ether') }
            )
            .send({ from: account.address });
```

I can confirm that if I remove the `require` from smart contract, everything works fine. My question is how to catch the error from smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `try/catch`, `catch` block would catch any error. "Insufficient fund" has specific error code:

```
const callCreateSector = () => {
  try {
    await contract.methods
      .createSector(
        web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalI),
        web3.utils.toBigInt(selectedCells[0].globalJ),
        web3.utils.toBigInt(1),
        web3.utils.toBigInt(1),
        { value: web3.utils.fromWei(cellPriceInWei, "ether") }
      )
      .send({ from: account.address });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === -32603 && error.data.code === -32000) {
      // This was your error code
      console.error("Write error message because of insufficient funds ...");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I am able to get the `code` from the error in catch. But where do you get `-32603` `-32000` from? Is it part of standard? I am getting `code=310`.

Comment: https://blog.devgenius.io/tips-to-handle-internal-json-rpc-error-on-metamask-4fc103051a8a